# App incompatible with device Huawei Y560-L01 on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

I have uploaded an app to Google Play. It's targetSdkVersion is 23 and minSdkVersion is 12.

The AndroidManifest.xml contains the following lines:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"/>
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.firebase.firebase_core, com.google.android.gms.measurement, com.google.android.gms.measurement.impl, com.google.firebase.iid, com.google.firebase, com.google.android.gms.tasks, com.google.android.gms"/>
```

The problem is that for the device Huawei Y560-L01 with Android version 5.1.1 the Google Play says the app is incompatible with this device.

Could you please tell me, what should I do to make this app able to install to this device from Google Play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your Huawei Y560-L01 hasn't the uses feature USB host.
Quoting the documentation:

> Because not all Android-powered devices are guaranteed to support the USB host APIs, include a  element that declares that your application uses the android.hardware.usb.host feature.

If you want to install it on your device you have to set it as not required:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" required="false" />
```